# incorrect syntax near 's'. unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I am kinda noob in programming, and I was wondering what I have done wrong here -  can some one help me out?

I am making a console app in which it syncs two databases, but when I try to insert the data into the table it throws this exception; The code is:

```
public static void AddInterationPath(SqlConnection conDS_ReleaseCri, DataRow dr)
{
    SqlCommand insertNewAreaPath = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO InterationPath (ID,NodePath) VALUES(" + dr[0].ToString() + ",'" + dr[2].ToString() + "')", conDS_ReleaseCriterions);
    insertNewAreaPath.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

public static void AddAreaPath(SqlConnection conDS_ReleaseCri, DataRow dr)
{
    SqlCommand insertNewAreaPath = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO AreaPath (ID,NodePath) VALUES(" + dr[0].ToString() + ",'" + dr[2].ToString() + "')", conDS_ReleaseCriterions);
    insertNewAreaPath.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

And I get the following exception:

> incorrect syntax near 's'. unclosed quotation mark after the character
>   string ')'

Comment: perhaps `dr[2]` contains quotes? you have to escape quotes (in TSQL simply double all singles quotes)

Comment: this kind of code is *very* vulnerable to SQL injection. Use [parameterized queries](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) or an ORM such as LINQ to SQL that takes care of escaping parameters.

Comment: An even better solution would be to use [SQL Transaction](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10223/Using-Transactions-in-ADO-NET) with [parameterized queries](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter). This will safeguard you, as well as allow you to execute multiple queries at once, without the huge overhead.

Answer (score 10):

The data you are inserting probably contains special characters like single quotes. Change to a parameterized query so the values are escaped properly. A good example and explanation is http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html.

[Edit: Added an example. ]

For example, replace the contents of your first function with:

```
SqlCommand insertNewAreaPath = new SqlCommand(
    "INSERT INTO InterationPath (ID, NodePath) VALUES(@ID, @NodePath)",     
    conDS_ReleaseCriterions);
insertNewAreaPath.Parameters.Add("@ID", dr[0]);
insertNewAreaPath.Parameters.Add("@NodePath", dr[2]);
insertNewAreaPath.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: +1 for the only right answer to the question. An inline sample may be helpful though, since you never know how long links remain valid.

Comment: Thanks alot guys it really helped me especially akton example :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have "'" inside of value of string then that type's of error is comming, So remove "'" from string then execute query.

Comment: That than doesn't copy the data as-is, does it?

Comment: This approach is very wrong. Not only it limits the data you want to write to the database, and still it leaves the SQL query prone to further errors. You'd use Query Parameters for that.

Comment: Thanks alot yes I will try to change the approach.