# How can I add auto numbering in visual c# 2010? using ms Access?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm using autonumber but it doesn't work for me. I want auto numbering in my StudentID number.

```
OleDbCommand system = new OleDbCommand();
system.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
system.CommandText = 
"insert into Student(ID, Lastname, Middlename, Firstname, Address, DateofBirth, Birthplace, Contact_number, emailaddress, guardian_name, Guardian_contact) values ('" + txtStudentIDnumber.Text + "','" + txtlastname.Text + "','" + txtfirstname.Text + "','" + 
txtmiddlename.Text + "','" + txtaddress.Text + "','" + txtdateofbirth.Text + "','" + txtbirthplace.Text + "','" + txtcontactnumber.Text + "','" + txtemailaddress.Text + "','" + txtGuardianname.Text + "','" + txtguardiancontact.Text + "')";
system.Connection = mydatabase;



if (MessageBox.Show("Save data?", "Confirm Save", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
```

Comment: How are you inserting rows?  (show code please)

Comment: You are most likely supplying a value for the autonumber column. If that's not the case, then show us your table description, as well as the insert statements.

Comment: i dont know what to do..im noob in c# sorry

Comment: also, I just noticed this. Your text-boxes aren't in the correct order. FirstName and MiddleName needs to be swapped around

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to determine the issue without the database schema or the error message. However, the issue is probably because you are trying to insert a value into the `ID` column when it may have auto numbering (also known as a counter) enabled. Change:

```
system.CommandText = "insert into Student(ID, Lastname, ..."; // And so on
```

to

```
system.CommandText = "insert into Student(Lastname, ..."; // And so on
```

Also consider changing the query to be a parameterized query (such as that mentioned in [incorrect syntax near 's'. unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244540/incorrect-syntax-near-s-unclosed-quotation-mark-after-the-character-string/12244623#12244623)) rather than using concatenation to avoid SQL injection and escaping issues.

Comment: when i run the system the textbox of StudentID has no number. what should i do?

Comment: @ansie23 Either generate a unique number and insert it into the ID field (assuming it is a primary key) or set the field to be AutoNumber as Sirwan has indicated.

Answer (score 2):

first you should specify identity Column like this :

[image]

then your code :

```
 OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\db.accdb");
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = string.Format("insert into Student(LastName,...) values('{0}',...)",txtLastName.Text.Trim(),...);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ID column should be setup to be an identity (in the database), then you should omit it from the insert.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1492834.aspx/1

**UPDATE**

I suspect your StudentIdNumber is an actual stateissued ID number, and what you're looking for is an identity field.

You'll need to add an identity column to your table, either using the table designer you used to create the table, or using a script

```
CREATE TABLE Student(
   ID int identity, 
   StudentIdNo varchar(10), 
   Lastname varchar(10), 
   Firstname varchar(10), 
   Middlename varchar(10), 
   CONSTRAINT AutoIncrementTest_PrimaryKey PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

*This will be the format of your insert statement, notice there is no ID field*

```
"INSERT INTO Student (StudentIdNo, Lastname, Firstname, Middlename) VALUES (?)"
```

***...in your case, after adding a identity field***

```
   OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand();
   comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

   comm.CommandText = 
       @"insert into Student(StudentIdNo, Lastname, Firstname, Middlename) 
                     values (@StudentIdNo, @Lastname, @Firstname, @Middlename)"; 

   comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentIdNo", txtStudentIdNo.Text);
   comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname", txtlastname.Text);
   comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", txtfirstname.Text);
   comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Middlename", txtmiddlename.Text);

   comm.Connection = mydatabase;
```